# Core Data fetch request one-to-many relationships with NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

If I have several entities lets say Genre, Artist, Song and there is a relationship between the three One-To-Many, how I go about searching artists within the Genre, given that I have a generic `NSFetchedResultsController`, that is in my `CoreManager` class that my tableviews conforms. The code works fine to request the content of the entity but I am not sure if I tapped on one of the Genres to display those artists within them and go to multiple levels.
My FRC code is

```
fetchedResultsController = {
    let request = fetchRequest
    request.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptor
    request.predicate = fetchPredicate
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    let context = managedContext
    let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(
        fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
        managedObjectContext: context,
        sectionNameKeyPath: sectionNameKeyPath , cacheName: cacheName)
    return frc
}()
```

[image]

Comment: Please can you provide more details of the model entities and relationships.  Thanks.

Comment: I updated the question with image to my model graph, I am only concerned for now in how to fetch all artists for example under specific Genre, how to call that in my FRC in the ArtistViewController. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your FRC to filter `Artists` by `Genre`, you will need to add a relationship from `Artist` to `Genre` (the inverse of the `artists` relationship on the `Genre` entity).  As a side note, you should almost always define an inverse for every relationship - there are very few situations where you are better off without an inverse.

I'm not sure whether you would regard each `Artist` as having only one `Genre`, or possibly having many - set the relationship as `to-one` or `to-many` as appropriate, and name it `genre` or `genres` accordingly.  The predicate that is then required will be different in each case:

For to-one, you should use

```
NSPredicate(format:"genre == %@", chosenGenre)
```

and for to-many you would use

```
NSPredicate(format:"ANY genres == %@", chosenGenre)
```

(assuming you already have a reference, `chosenGenre`, to the genre you wish to filter by.  If you in fact have only the genre title, you would use:

```
NSPredicate(format:"genre.title == %@", chosenGenreTitle)
```

and for to-many you would use

```
NSPredicate(format:"ANY genres.title == %@", chosenGenreTitle)
```

Comment: I totally get the idea of the relationships you explained. My model is just a draft and my main focus at this moment to get my head around how to fetch the items related to specific object, like you shown here ```chosenGenre``` or ```chosenGenre```, that reference is it an ```indexPath```, is it the whole genre object passed from the ```genreViewController``` to ```artistViewController```, this is the part I am not sure how it is done. If it is possible to help me understand that part :)?

Comment: `chosenGenre` is an actual `Genre` object.  Assuming genreViewController is a tableViewController, with rows displaying details for individual Genre objects, when the user taps a row, you would lookup the correct Genre based on the indexPath, and pass that Genre to the ArtistViewController.  The ArtistViewController uses that Genre object in the predicate for its FRC.